# OSX: detect 'restricted' filesystem flag programmatically

Tags: swift, macos

Starting from El Capitan the system got System Integrity Protection which doesn't allow certain activities for some folders and files. Using Terminal "ls lO" command you can see flags that specific file or folder has.

```
drwxr-xr-x@   3 root  wheel  hidden                96 Aug 12  2014 opt
drwxr-xr-x    6 root  wheel  sunlnk,hidden        192 Nov 28 15:14 private
drwxr-xr-x@  64 root  wheel  restricted,hidden   2048 Nov 29 13:48 sbin
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root  wheel  restricted,hidden     11 Nov 28 15:13 tmp -> private/tmp
drwxr-xr-x@  10 root  wheel  restricted,hidden    320 Nov 28 15:21 usr
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root  wheel  restricted,hidden     11 Nov 28 15:13 var -> private/var
```

I'm interested in "restricted" flag. How can it be found using Swift without executing terminal commands?

I want to emphasize that executing Process() in code is not an approach that suits the needs.

"Hidden" flag can be detected via "isHidden" property from here [URLResourceKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcekey). However there is nothing about "restricted".

Could somebody point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The things listed by the `-O` option on the `ls` tool are the file flags. These can be read by the `stat()` function in the BSD layer, and are found in the `st_flags` field of the resulting structure.

The "restricted" flag in `ls`'s output corresponds to `SF_RESTRICTED`, so you can read it by doing something like this:

```
func isRestricted(at url: URL) throws -> Bool {
    let flags: UInt32 = try url.withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation { fsRep in
        var info = stat()

        if stat(fsRep, &info) != 0 {
            guard let code = POSIXError.Code(rawValue: errno) else {
                throw CocoaError(.fileReadUnknown)
            }

            throw POSIXError(code)
        }

        return info.st_flags
    }

    return flags & UInt32(bitPattern: SF_RESTRICTED) != 0
}
```